Don't know where sump pump drains
We bought our house in 2015, it was built in 2005. The sump pump output hose goes in to a PVC pipe under the stairs of our house and there is no visible output on the outside of the house. Our backyard gets REALLY soggy and I am 99% sure it's because of the sump pump draining too close to the house.
I have gone to city hall to see if they had any information as to where it drains and, unfortunately, they don't.
Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could figure out where it comes out besides digging and digging and digging? The area in which I believe it is draining is under a bed of river rock that resides under our deck, which we can access but digging through the rock is challenging. Also, not sure if it's worth mentioning, but none of the houses in our neighborhood have visible sump pump outputs which I have always thought was odd. And it does not drain to the sewer.

Is the backyard soggy all over or in one spot/small area?  You want the end of the sump pump drain to be in the open, so no flow resistance.  A soggy spot in the yard might point to a broken section of the pipe.  You want excess water far away from the house, draining under the deck is a bit useless.  Look where the pipe comes out of house, see which way the ground slopes away.  If done right, that should be the direction.

Note that frequently soggy ground may be why you need a sump pump rather than the reverse...

The dye will help to show whether the soggy backyard is flowing into the pump and away to places unknown, or out of the pump (and quite possibly in circles...)

Put some non-toxic septic dye (florescent tracer dye) in the sump pit, and look for color in the soggy back yard later.
Common stuff, comes either as a liquid or in a dry form that dissolves, multiple colors available, highly visible.
That covers general exit locale, and may help you spot it when digging, but if looking for a specific spot to dig, hire a service (or see if your tool rental place has a device for rent) to run a tracer wire down the pipe under the stairs and locate it (from above ground using a detector that looks for the tracer wire signal) outside.

Thank you for your suggestions! A year or two ago I put a bottle of red food coloring in the sump pit, but we didn't see any red come out. I assumed it had gotten pretty filtered out. And a friend suggested sending an air tag through the hose to trace where it goes but I didn't love that idea. I'm gonna try the fluorescent dye you mentioned and the tracer wire. The sogginess in the backyard makes me crazy, so I'm willing to try it all. Thanks again!

Sounds like the sump is draining into a dry well. There are many good reasons to have a dry well, for example, in some communities you are forbidden from pumping any water near the property line.
If it's just that the yard gets a little soggy when you are pumping a lot, look at it as the price of having a dry basement. If you are determined to fix it, you will probably have to dig and install a new, larger dry well. If the dry well is under the deck, that means lots of labor, which gets expensive really quick.

Seems like more of a comment than actually answering the question. If you need more dry well, it's usually more cost effective to run a pipe to a second one than to dig out one and dig in a bigger one. If you're going to buy and dig for the bigger one, might as well do it in a different spot and have both working for you. The only add-on there is the pipe and trench beweeen them, which is minor compared to the well itself.
